# Get tags for an API via Java library

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm new with customization of WSO2 AM. 
There is a simple way to get the tags associated to a specific published API?
I would like to customize the logic of workflow subscription step checking some specific tags defined into the Publisher.

Answer (score 0):

[WSO2 API Manager Publisher REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/apidocs/publisher/#!/operations#APICollectionApi#apisApiIdGet) will help you to access API Manager publisher APIs programatically via REST API. There you can get API details by calling following API
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/apidocs/publisher/#!/operations#APICollectionApi#apisApiIdGet

See sample request details

```
URL
https://apis.wso2.com/api/am/publisher/v0.9/apis/{apiId}

HTTP Method
GET

Scope
apim:api_view

CURL Example
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer b0982cd2aacd463ff5f63cd5ebe58f4a" http://127.0.0.1:9763/api/am/publisher/v0.9/apis/890a4f4d-09eb-4877-a323-57f6ce2ed79b
```

In response you will get tags associated with API as follows.

```
"tags":    [
      "phone",
      "multimedia",
      "mobile"
   ],
```

Thnaks,

sanjeewa